# How to share folder with DOS on VirtualBox

Tags: 10.04, virtualbox, shared-folders

The host is Ubuntu 10.04,and I have already installed FreeDOS on VirtualBox.Since I can't get to the Internet on FreeDOS,I hava to share some files with FreeDOS.But how?

I know how to share a folder with a Linux guest,but there are no file for DOS in VBoxGuestAdditions.iso.

I find [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_with_DOS) but its host is WindowXP.

**How can I share folders with a DOS guest and Ubuntu host in VirtualBox?**

Answer (score 1):

"Shared Folders" in the sense of a driver that provides this functionality is not available for Virtual Box when running DOS as a guest.

You may be able to share DOS guest data with the Ubuntu host by setting up a network share using a Samba capable DOS client. I can't give you a concise howto as I have not done this before due to lack of time and lack of interest in DOS but I can give you some hints on what you need in case you go on with that.

- A samba capable client for DOS (eg. Microsoft [MS Client](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/BusSys/Clients/MSCLIENT/) or the [Lan Manager for DOS](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/BusSys/Clients/LANMAN/)
- Samba on the host needs to be enabled to use the old authentification (`lanman auth=yes`)
- DOS and Ubuntu need to be on the same Workgroup

Still there are limitations as you will not be able to get access to your DOS vdi from your host OS (you are only running a client on DOS) but if all is set up you may be able to send data from DOS to Ubuntu.

The [guide](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_with_DOS) you already found is a good starting point for the DOS side. Another nice tutorial on setting up samba for DOS can be found [here](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/samba/dos.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this might help but I was successful in installation of a big application through CD ROM.

1. First of all, you need to have CD ROM enabled.
   I installed VB VDI image from this link:
    https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/ms-dos-and-windows-3-1https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/ms-dos-and-windows-3-1
2. When you right click the mouse, you can see 'compress' in the menu and you can find 'iso' type to compress a file or a folder into iso format.
3. Then, under device menu on top of Ubuntu desktop, you can see 'CD/DVD device -> choose a virtual CD/DVD file' menu.

If you want to export any file from DOS, please use FDD since you haven't create a large file yet.

Good luck.

Comment: 404 not found...